# spring-batch job monitoring and restart

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am new to spring-batch, got few questions:-

I have got a question about the restart. As per documentation, the restart feature is enabled by default. What I am not clear is do I need to do any extra code for a restart? If so, I am thinking of adding a scheduled job that looks at failed processes and restarts them?

I understand spring-batch-admin is deprecated. However, we cannot use spring-cloud-data-flow right now. Is there any other alternative to monitor and restart jobs on demand?

Answer (score 1):

The restart that you mention only means if a job is restartable or not .It doesn't mean Spring Batch will help you to restart the failed job automatically.

Instead, it provides the following building blocks for developers for achieving this task on their own :

- [`JobExplorer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) to find out the id of the job execution that you want to restart
- [`JobOperator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/JobOperator.html) to restart a job execution given a job execution id

Also , a restartable job can only be restarted if its status is `FAILED`. So if you want to restart a running job that was stop running because of the server breakdown , you have to first find out this running job and update its job execution status and all of its task execution status to `FAILED` first in order to restart it. (See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job) for more information). One of the solution is to implement a `SmartLifecycle` which use the above building blocks to achieve this goal.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I wanted to check if uncompleted jobs start by itself. I understand if I want to retry a failed job I would have to use JobExplorer/JobOperator. Would you any alternative for spring-batch-admin other than spring-data-cloud-flow

Comment: please see my update my answer , and not sure if `https://github.com/tuxdevelop/spring-batch-lightmin` is an alternative for spring-batch-admin for achieving your goal. But it is not so difficult to do it by yourself using those building blocks , so give it a try first

Comment: Thanks, will check.